# How to correlate related custom logs using ILogger and application insights?

Tags: .net, azure, logging, azure-application-insights, .net-core-logging

I have a service, that performs some REST API calls and I do custom logging before and after the api call:

```cs
_logger.LogTrace("Invoked API {ApiName}", new { ApiName = apiName, Data = json });

var httpResponse = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(json));
httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var responseDto = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<ResponseDto>(httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStream())!;

if (!responseData.Success)
{
    _logger.LogWarning("Failed API {ApiName}", new { ApiName = apiName, Data = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() });
}
```

The HttpClient also produces logs.

What is the recommended approach for correlating the logs, so that I can easily find related logs in application insights portal?

I would like all logs produced by HttpClient or possibly ADO.NET etc to be related to my custom log.

EDIT:
I know ASP.NET Core MVC or Pages automatically correlate logs using an OperationTelemetry per request. I need the same for other scenarios: console app, rich client, blazor server (uses websockets instead requests)

Comment: what about generating a GUID and adding them as property to all the logs? then you can include it in your insights query

Comment: The code you show, is it executed by a controller action?

Comment: Mostly no, but sometimes yes. I need to make it work in blazor server which doesn't use http request/response). It's more like a rich client app.
I know the controller action starts an operation and httpcontext produces dependency telemetries related to the operation. Unfortunately, I have managed to make this work in Blazor Server

Comment: @Liero ok got it. I think I have a solution in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, telemetry is only automatically linked when it is part of an operation. An operation is created when a controller receives a request for example. That is done by the runtime.

In cases you don't have a pending operation you will need to manually add context so you can relate telemetry or you can create your own operation to associate telemetry to that specific operation. You can do so like this:

```cs
using (var op = _telemetryClient.StartOperation<DependencyTelemetry>($"Invoke API {ApiName}"))
{
    _logger.LogTrace("Invoked API {ApiName}", new { ApiName = apiName, Data = json });

    var httpResponse = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(json));
    httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var responseDto = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<ResponseDto>(httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStream())!;

    if (!responseData.Success)
    {
        op.Telemetry.Success = false;
        _logger.LogWarning("Failed API {ApiName}", new { ApiName = apiName, Data = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() });
    }
}
```

Now all telemetry will be correlated inside the scope of the operation.

Comment: Just follow up question: what is recomended lifetime scope for telemetryclient? Let's say I have a Blazor Server app, which is a basically asp.net core app, hosting multiple long living blazor sessions (blazor session ~= on tab in a browser until closed or refreshed)

Comment: It should be a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

The ILogger logs are automatically correlated, if you enable the entire ApplicationInsights for Asp.Net Core following this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core
For example, all logs will have same operationId, if they are done as part of the same request.

Also check:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation

Comment: That does not work for non-web code like console apps

Comment: yes. For apps without an existing context/request, one must create own to wrap.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to just add your own correlation ID, then you can do so using logger data scopes:

```
using (logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>{
    ["OperationId"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
}))
{
  ... // logs from any code in here will have an OperationId
}
```

Comment: But then it is still not correlated to the other Application Insights telemetry as it is not part of the same operation.