# Sharing variable of context to another service

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement app insight in my WebApi. I want to correlate my logs from control and to all the service that I call inside my controller. I am trying to pass the correlationId from one class to other class but it doesn't seem to work.  How can I share correlation from one context/controller down to the services that use ILogger class.

In my controller I am using LoggingContext class to log information for my controller. I instantiate LoggingContext inside my controller and pass the correlationid in constructor. Is there a way I can share the correlation Id to other class that get called in the ValuesController-> Get call.

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
 {
     private readonly ITestService _testService;

     public ValuesController(ITestService testService)
     {
         _testService = testService;
     }
     // GET api/values
     public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Get()


     {
         var correlationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
         using (var logging = new LoggingContext(correlationId))
         {
             await logging.LogInformation("This is a test message");

             await _testService.GetAll();
         }
         return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
     }
 }
```

How can I pass the correlationId from LoggingContext to the Logger class, so that the next user of the logger will get the same correlation Id that I pass in the controller.

```
public class LoggingContext : IDisposable
{

    public LoggingContext(string correlationId)
    {   
        
        Logger.CorrelationId = correlationId; // 
    }
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
    public async Task LogInformation(string message)
    {

        await Logger.LogInformation(message);
    }
   
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}

public interface ILogger
{
    Task LogInformation(string message);
    //Task LogInformation(string message, object data);
    string CorrelationId { get; set; }
}

public class Logger : ILogger
{
   
    public Logger()
    {
    }
    public string CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public async Task LogInformation(string message)
    {
        
    }

}
```

If I call the ILogger here the correlationId get change.

```
public class TestService : ITestService
 {
     private readonly ILogger _logger;
     public TestService(ILogger logger)
     {
         _logger = logger;
     }
     public async Task<string> GetAll()
     {
         await _logger.LogInformation("This is a test message from Test Service");
         return new string[] { "value1", "value2" }.ToString();
     }
 }
 public interface ITestService
 {
     Task<string> GetAll();
 }
```

Comment: Elaborate on "next user of the logger".  Next user as in other instances of your logger within the same request? Or user as in a human using the API? Or?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74042775/how-to-correlate-related-custom-logs-using-ilogger-and-application-insights

Comment: @mxmissile, other instance of logger within the same request.

Comment: Can't you just inject `LoggingContext` as Scoped?